# Etymology/Origin behind using "bitching" in a positive sense

Tags: etymology

Etymonline.com mentions this:

> **bitch** (v.)
>   "to complain," attested at least from 1930, perhaps from the sense in bitchy, perhaps influenced by the verb meaning "to bungle, spoil," which is recorded from 1823. But bitched in this sense seems to echo Middle English bicched "cursed, bad," a general term of opprobrium (as in Chaucer's bicched bones "unlucky dice"), which despite the hesitation of OED, seems to be a derivative of bitch (n.).

and then we have:

> **bitching** (adj.) 
>   also bitchen, "good," teen/surfer slang attested from 1950s, apparently from bitch (v.) in some inverted sense.

How did the second, positive meaning arise from the first extremely negative (and long) history of the word? What and where are the earliest uses of the word in this newer positive meaning?

Comment: "Bad is the new good." In slang's search for new and better in-group intensifiers, negative terms are often appropriated and spun in the other direction. Cf. *killer*, *sick*, *wicked*, and even *bad*.

Comment: This is how we got "cool" from "hot", etc.  It's just natural for slang to resort to an opposite of an over-used term.

Comment: OED lists this usage under the same entry as the earlier senses *to hang back* and *to bungle*, first recorded 1777 and 1823 respectively. Origin uncertain, but *may* derive from the *female dog* noun. Or, by implication, may not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not able to find etymologies in the non-paid online version of oxford or elsewhere online. Is this available anywhere outside a paywall?

Comment: The uncertainty is referenced by [etymonline:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bitch) ***bitched** in this sense seems to echo Middle English **bicched** "cursed, bad," a general term of opprobrium (as in Chaucer's **bicched bones** "unlucky dice"), which **despite the hesitation of OED,** seems to be a derivative of **bitch (noun)**.* See also [*A Concise of Middle   English*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/10625/10625-h/dict1.html) **Bicched,** pp. a word of doubtful meaning, applied to the basilisk, and to bones used for dice, NED, CM, C3; byched, MD; bichede, NED.

Comment: ...I get free access to OED V3 through my (UK) library card number. Full price is £240 a year - but it is *the* definitive dictionary for English, and you can't even buy it as dead trees any more. Last I knew, the paper edition V2 used to be £750, but even at that price it was costing them money to produce it. I think there might be a way to access OED V1 online, but only as scanned images, not indexed searchable *text*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J.E. Lighter, *The Random House Dictionary of American Slang* (1994) reports that the origin of bitching in a positive sense was student use:

> **bitching** *adj.*, ... 2. *Stu.* excellent, wonderful, exceptionally attractive. Also, **bitchen**.
>
> [First two cited occurrences:] **1957** Kohner *Gidget* 10: It was a bitchen day too. The sun was out...in Southern California. **1962** *English Jrnl.* (May) 323: *Bitchin'* equivalent to neat or swell.

The instance in Frederick Kohner, [*Gidget*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ve7IejQ78mYC&pg=PT15&dq=%22It+was+a+bitchen+day+too%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9DNqVZPNCtatyASb7oGwCA&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22It%20was%20a%20bitchen%20day%20too%22&f=false) (1957) reads in context this way:

> I tried it. I was sort of desperate to write this story  so I drove out to the main drag (I got my junior license only last week) all by myself, and I took that pencil and notebook along and was all set to begin at the beginning. I mean with the description of the place. It was a **bitchen** day, too. The sun was out and all that, even though it was near the end of November. But then, we are living in Southern California and if you wouldn't look at the calendar you'd hardly know the difference—honest!

*Gidget* is a surfer-girl novel, written by the real-life father of the original gidget (*gidget*, we learn, is a surfer palindrome for "girl midget"). A discussion of the book and of the California surfer subculture of 1957 in "[Gidget Makes the Grade](https://books.google.com/books?id=5lYEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA111&dq=%22bitchen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zDVqVbmADtPVoAS49ILYAw&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22bitchen%22&f=false)," in *Life* magazine (October 28, 1957) reveals another instance of *bitchen* in that subculture:

> The book tells how Gidget learned the difficult art of surfboarding—catching the "**bitchen** wetbacks" (big waves) and "shooting the curls" (riding the surf) without "getting the ax" (falling under a breaker). An indomitable girl, Gidget finally masters the board.

I don't recall ever having encountered the term *wetbacks* except as an derisive (and offensive) name for *braceros*—unlicensed Mexican nationals who cross over the U.S.-Mexican border to pick crops and perform other hard labor in the United States. (The term *wetback* refers to their having supposedly crossed the border (illegally) by swimming across the Rio Grande, which forms the entire border between Texas and Mexico from Brownsville/Matamoros on the Gulf of Mexico to El Paso/Ciudad Juarez in far west Texas.

In any event, the positive sense of *bitching* can apply to *bitch* as well, as this glossary entry in "[The Parlance of Hip](https://books.google.com/books?id=0EFXAAAAYAAJ&q=%22bitchin%22&dq=%22bitchin%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2mBqVYjoLomkoQTotYDwCg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBDhG)," in *Esquire*, volume 52 (1959) indicates:

> BITCH: something very good. Example: That song is beautiful. That musician has a **bitchin'** ear. *Bitch* also means girl or woman, but not in a derogatory sense. Example: I've got me a fine **bitch**.

The "not in a derogatory sense" language here may be intended to indicate that a a person using the term may not mean to convey the idea that the girl or woman so designated is unpleasant or unattractive in any way, but the notion that "bitch" is therefore not derogatory appears to be a relic of a particular (and peculiar) male view of the subject at the height of the *Mad Men* era.

And a glossary in the [*Saturday Evening Post*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bSgfAQAAMAAJ&q=%22bitching%22&dq=%22bitching%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FMpqVcDqA5eyoQSO5oHYBw&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgo), volume 234 (1961) has this entry for *bitching*, along with entries such as "like wow," "like cool, man," and "swinging":

> **bitching** — joyous term, as in: "I had a bitching (or joyous) time."

Wentworth & Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang* (1960) find an even earlier antecedent for *bitching* in a positive sense in *bitchey*:

> **bitchy, bitchey** *adj.* **1** Having the attributes of a bitch. **2** Striking in appearance; classy. 1930: "A pearl-gray Stutz, a bitchey roadster, all right." J[ames] T. Farrell, 137. *Some c1930 use.*

The Farrell citation comes from a short story called "[Looking 'Em Over](https://books.google.com/books?id=KOyfpN40l0wC&pg=PA23&dq=Stutz,+a+bitchey+roadster&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1s1qVYCHLcnqoATjw4DABw&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Stutz%2C%20a%20bitchey%20roadster&f=false)" (1930).

It's not impossible that the use of *bitchin'* in 1950s surfer lingo directly recalls the early 1930s usage of *bitchey* in a similarly upbeat sense. But it may be even more likely that the adjective *bitching* (or its more elaborate sibling *son-of-a-bitching*), popularized by soldiers during World War II and the Korean War, provided the inspiration for the newly positive *bitchin'*. In any event, it seems truer to attribute its origin to the surf lingo of Southern California in the late 1950s than to student use, as Lighter unaccountably does after noting its early occurrence in *Gidget*.

Answer (score 2):

As Etymonline suggests, it may be just an inverted sense of the term 'bitch'. It appears that it was first used  in South California.

[Bitchin](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/bitchin'):

> very good, excellent; "cool"; "awesome". Origin and notes: Bitching is a somewhat dated term that has made several comebacks. It is rare to hear it today. *Believed to have originated in the surfer crowd of Southern California, USA, circa the 1960s - 1970s. Also spelled bitchen'.*

Source:http://onlineslangdictionary.com

[Bitchin](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bitching):

> adjective Slang (US) 
>   marvelous; wonderful.
>   Also, bitch·en, bitch·ing [bich-ing, -uhn].
>
> Origin: 
>   bitch + -in’, -en  informal or dialectal variant of -ing2  (here forming nonparticipial adj.)

Source: http://dictionary.reference.com

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to note "Bitch" in the context of music can refer to an especially gifted performer. This usage can be seen, for instance, in Miles Davis's "Bitches Brew" and Elton John's "The Bitch is back." This is a jazz-era term, so it seems in line with the definition attributed to 1950s teen/surfer culture.